# hosting an ASP.Net winapp in my WinForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I've working on a C# winform application for a few years now, that needs to be able to host a web backend over localhost. Currently im just using the System.Net.HttpListener object as a built in webserver, and then using T4 to parse the html that will be sent to the browser. I recently started working with Asp.NET MVC 2.0 and was wondering if it was possible to replace my old HttpListener and T4 templates, and use Asp.Net in its place? I notice ive been able to reference Mvc dll files from my asp.net projects, is there a way that i can get the generated webpages from these dll's?

Note: The service just needs to be running when the application is running, doesnt need to be running 24/7.

Comment: Do you want to use ASP.NET Webforms or Razor for the pages?

Comment: I prefer to use just the base ASP.net